# fullcalendar RTL options for day and week views

Tags: fullcalendar

When using isRTL : true 
shouldn't the week and day view - hours column - display on the right side ? 
i'm using it like that

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    flag = !1;
    $("#Xcalendar").fullCalendar({
        theme: !0,
        isRTL : true,
        header: { left: "next,prev today", center: "title", right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay" },
```

I'm using version 1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested in my calendar and the month view is displayed Rigt to Left but the week and day view are displayed in the default way LTR...

I am using the 1.6 version, so i guess its suposed to be like that...